# drawing on an image in an imageview in android

Tags: android, drawing

I load an image into an imageview. the image is 72x72 px

I want to get every pixel user touched in that imageview, and draw a point there.

this is what i have in onTouchListener for imageview:

```
ImageView inneriv = (ImageView)arg0;
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(arg1.getX()));
tv2.setText(String.valueOf(arg1.getY()));
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.CYAN);
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) inneriv.getDrawable();
Bitmap b = bd.getBitmap().copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawPoint(arg1.getX(), arg1.getY(), p);
inneriv.setImageBitmap(b);
inneriv.invalidate();
```

i made the imageview to scale to whole screen (although there is a button and two textviews, and this fits below them).

the problem is that when i touch on imageview, nothing get drawn. but when i touch the 72x72 sqaure on left top of imageview (inside that), i get cyan points on imageview. it is as if whole image is on 72x72 and it is just scaled, and doesnt respond to touch events in anywhere else. when i touch anywhere, i can see X and Y on two textviews, but nothing gets painted. maybe there is a scale option or something that i am not aware of.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can I see all of your code? As in the entire MainActivity.java file, or at the very minimum any part where you handle the onclick. It doesn't seem that you're even handling click events at all here, so I need to see the rest.

Comment: this is the whole code inside the onTouchListener for my ImageView. arg0 is the ImageVew and arg1 is the MotionEvent. and I really don't do anyting inside onCreate, except this (calling setOnTouchListener).

Comment: Do the textviews display the right x,y values? Also, note that if you have an actionbar you'll have to subtract that height from everything.

Comment: textviews show correct x and y. I have an actionbar (default eclipse-made activity), but that doesn't seem to be my problem. why only a square, with equal size to the real image?